# How to fix this "type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace"?

Tags: c#, forms

I created an Error Window for a previous project and I want to reuse it in a new project rather than create a new one, so I used this Add Existing Item feature to add the Error Form and its resources from Project A (the name of the first solution). The Error Form also has a PictureBox on it.

However, when I imported the Error Form into the Project B, I get this
"The type or namespace name 'Properties' does not exist in the namespace".

The offending line:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = global::<ProjectA>.Properties.Resources.imgName;
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: So you copied the form (using Add Existing Item) but you didn't copy the resources?

Comment: I did copy them too, just edited.

Comment: Interesting. As far as I'm aware, the `namespace` declared in the Resources `.Designer.cs` file shouldn't change when adding it to a different project. Anyway, you should check this file and see what the namespace is.